# How should the environment variables of the vscode plugin be set?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I tried to set it with cross-env, but it was undefined after running with VSCode. How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Actually, you might be launching your extension for development differently than me. Can you post the full line of your "watch" script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass environment variables to VS Code extensions you run locally via the launch configuration:

**./.vscode/launch.json**

```
// A launch configuration that compiles the extension and then opens it inside a new window
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Run Extension",
            "type": "extensionHost",
            "request": "launch",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${execPath}",
            "args": [
                "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}"
            ],
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/dist/extension.js"
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "${defaultBuildTask}",
            "env": {
                "DEBUG": "true" // <---- EXAMPLE ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: In fact, I just want to use this to distinguish between development/production environments. Does `vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get("debug.console.fontSize")` get any value in the production environment?

Comment: Ah, you were on the right track then, you should use an environment variable for that. You can set that in launch.json, I changed my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, after the actual test to determine availability. Sorry, I use JetBrains WebStorm for development everyday, but there are some non-production environment codes (such as writing markdown documents) that need to use VSCode a lot, so I will appear to be able to write VSCode plugins, but I don’t understand the `launch.json` configuration Strange situation