# How to set VS Code environment secrets from GitHub Actions

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, github-actions, vscode-extensions

I am building a VS Code extension using GitHub Actions for various OS. I need to set environment variables before building extension for few API access. I am not able to understand how to use GitHub Actions secrets to populate environment variables.

I went through [How should the environment variables of the vscode plugin be set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62493776/how-should-the-environment-variables-of-the-vscode-plugin-be-set) on how can I set env variables for VS Code extensions. But this doesn't cover the case of GitHub Actions as I don't understand how can I add in `launch.json` the secrets coming from GitHub Actions secrets

The secret is constant for everyone and it is required to access some API. Now I don't want any user to add anything to the environment variables but the builder of extension should be able to access them and pass it to extension without the user knowing the secrets. Even something other than environment variable might work but I am not sure how.

Comment: So your build is failing in github actions? or you are able to install extensions from vscode marketplace but it is unable to read the local environment variables?

Comment: Basically, I need an API URL and key (Both are secret). So these are constant for anyone. However, I don't want any user (user of the extension) to access them and there is a UI interface inside the extension through which this should be used. Now, I am not able to send these while building or on run time. Even some alternative methods other than using environment variables might work which I don't know about. It's not about user adding the environment variable but adding it on build/package time of extension